# Core Plot 1.0: Barchart is starting with the wrong bar (depending on Barplot.Offset)

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

### Problem

I am drawing a bar chart with **Core Plot**. My implementation of the `numberForPlot` as the data source seems to return the values correctly. However, depending on the setting of `barPlot.Offset` the chart starts with the wrong value.

### Datasource implementation

I have implemented the datasource as follows:

```
- (NSArray *)numbersForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot 
                 field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum 
      recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange; 

if(fieldEnum == 3) {

NSString *coa = [[NSString alloc] init];
coa = (NSString*)[plot identifier];

NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
for (IBFinPeriod *fp in periodsArray) {
    NSNumber *value = [self.company valueForCoa:coa FiscalYear:[fp FiscalYear] FiscalPeriod:[fp FiscalPeriod]];
    [values addObject:value];
    }
NSLog(@"plot values: %@",values);
return values;

}
else

    return    [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
               [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:2.0],
               [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:3.0],
               [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:4.0],
               [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:5.0],
               nil]; 
}
```

This code returns the **y-values**: "1841.059",
    "2492.619",
    "3011.582",
    "2643.865",
    "2914.845",
    "3470.457", which is correct.

### Barplot offset

However, only when `barPlot.barOffset  = CPTDecimalFromFloat(-0.50f);`
 the plot starts correctly with the first value on the left.

[image: chart with barPlot.offset = -0.50f]

If `barPlot.barOffset`
is set to 0, it starts with the left half of the last value (3470.57):

[image: chart with barPlot.offset = 0.00f]

### Chart set-up

This is the code to set-up the chart:

```
- (void) setChart;
```

{
    graph1 = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];

```
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
[graph1 applyTheme:theme];
self.chartLeft.hostedGraph = graph1;
graph1.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;


// Border
graph1.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
graph1.plotAreaFrame.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

// Paddings
graph1.paddingLeft  = 10.0;
graph1.paddingTop   = 10.0;
graph1.paddingRight = 10.0;
graph1.paddingBottom = 10.0;

graph1.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 50.0;
graph1.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 20.0;
graph1.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 20.0;
graph1.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 50.0;
graph1.plotAreaFrame.backgroundColor = nil;

graph1.paddingLeft = 20.0;
graph1.paddingTop = 20.0;
graph1.paddingRight = 20.0;
graph1.paddingBottom = 20.0;

// Setup plot space
// The plot space determines the data ranges that are visible in the graph, not its physical size in the view
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph1.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(4000.0f)];
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(5.0f)];

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph1.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
x.axisLineStyle               = nil;
x.majorTickLineStyle          = nil;
x.minorTickLineStyle          = nil;
x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1");
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
x.title                       = @"X Axis";
x.titleLocation               = CPTDecimalFromFloat(7.5f);
x.titleOffset                 = 55.0f;

// Custom labels omitted...

CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.axisLineStyle               = nil;
y.majorTickLineStyle          = nil;
y.minorTickLineStyle          = nil;
y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1000");
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
y.title                       = @"Y Axis";
y.titleOffset                 = 45.0f;
y.titleLocation               = CPTDecimalFromFloat(150.0f);

// First bar plot
CPTBarPlot *barPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor darkGrayColor] horizontalBars:NO];
barPlot.baseValue  = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
barPlot.barOffset  = CPTDecimalFromFloat(-0.50f);
barPlot.identifier = @"SOPI";
barPlot.dataSource = self;
[graph1 addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
```

}

### Question

What is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about setting `barPlot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromFloat(-0.50f)`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

My return statement for the x values was missing numberWithFloat 6.0

```
return    [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:2.0],
           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:3.0],
           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:4.0],
           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:5.0],
           nil];
```

In addition, the length in `plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(5.0f)]`was only 5. However, I have 6 x-values. I have set the length to 6.5 now. However, when setting it to 6.0, the right bar is shown